# How do I restore a TestFlight App after restoring from iCloud Backup

Tags: ios, iphone, testflight

I recently factory reset my iPhone, after I finished restoring my phone with iCloud Backup. When I tried to install one of my Testflight Apps by tapping the App icon, it shows me the following error

[image: Unable to Install App]

And when I go to Testflight, it shows me an option to install. Pressing "Install" will overwrite my existing App and erase the backed-up App data, is there any way to restore a TestFlight App from iCloud Backup?

Comment: Installing from TestFlight will not erase the data.  It just installs the app

Comment: I have stored some data in the iOS keychain via the App. Specifically, I used the `expo-secure-store` package, where I have set `kSecAttrAccessible` to WHEN_UNLOCKED_THIS_DEVICE_ONLY, `kSecAccessControlBiometryCurrentSet` to true.

After I installed the App from Testflight, I tried to fetch the value from the keychain but the data was not there any more. Any idea what I should do here?

Comment: Come to terms with the fact that the data is gone?